# Excel Macro: conditional cut and paste between workbooks

Tags: excel, paste, worksheet

So I want a macro running in an Excel file ("input.xls") that is searching a column in another Excel file ("data.xls") for the value "1" (the only values in that columns are 1s and 0s). When it finds a "1," it should copy and paste the entire row from that file into "input.xls".

Here is the code that I have

```
Sub NonErrorDataParse()
    Dim intEnd As Integer

    Workbooks("data.xls").Sheets("Raw").Activate

    intEnd = 65000

    Range("F").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Row = intEnd

        If Int(ActiveCell.Value) = 1 Then
            Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row).Cut
            intEnd = intEnd - 1
            Workbooks("input.xls").Sheets("Non-errors").Activate
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

However, when I run it, it gives me a "subscript out of range" error on "data.xls." No matter how I fiddle with the code I can't seem to get past that error (even though I have OTHER macros that are accessing that sheet that work fine).

Any ideas as to how to fix it? Or better code that will do the same thing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you first sort the data.xls ? You could then calculate a single cut & paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to `Select` or `Activate` each time you do a command.
You can also find the last used cell with `Range("A65536").End(xlup)` instead of parsing every cell (that probably caused your error).

The code would then look like:

```
Sub NonErrorDataParse()
    Dim intEnd As Integer
    Dim c As Range

    intEnd = Workbooks("data.xls").Sheets("Raw").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Workbooks("data.xls").Sheets("Raw").Range("F1:F" & intEnd)
       If CStr(c.Value) = "1" Then
           c.EntireRow.Cut
           Workbooks("input.xls").Sheets("Non-errors").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
       End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Yet, if you have many rows, it would be faster to use the `autofilter` method or use a dictionary.

Comment: This code gave me "Compile error: User-defined type not defined."

Comment: @Billy: sorry, my mistake, i didn't had time to check in the editor. I corrected my code

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still isn't working. It doesn't give me an error message, but it just isn't cutting and pasting into the new workbook. I fiddled around with it, but it won't even work if I change it to between worksheets instead of between workbooks, or if I use different workbooks.

Comment: i made a little change (added `Workbooks("data.xls").Sheets("Raw").` so that we're sure Excel won't misunderstand the wb we're trying to cut) but i'm not sure this is it and i can't test right here. I'll make a full test tomorrow with some sample files. Excel is sometimes tricky with copy/paste. Yet, if you want to try, you can debug and execute the macro step by step to see where it fails :)

Comment: @Billy: i made some changes and it worked for me (note i used an optional `CStr` in case the cell you want to check doesn't have the right format)